# dropdown list that refresh a div content upon select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have totally no idea about how to do this, so i'm gonna just ask away.

I have a dropdown menu which list dates say

```
1/2/2013
2/2/2013
3/2/2013
4/2/2013
5/2/2013
6/2/2013
7/2/2013
```

if you were to select one of the dates, a div will pop out with say 5 choices

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

each choices are stored in the database, and if say B item is not available on 2/2/2013, i would have a script to disable it being selected. I've figured how to create that in php, but my ultimate question is

how do you select any of the dates but yet still able to retrieve the 5 choices from a database?

I'm currently doing something like this

```
function TheDisabler($aa)
{
global $con, $vdate;    

    $myresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM burger WHERE timeslot = '$aa' AND date = '$vdate'");
    list($mycount) = mysqli_fetch_row($myresult);

    if($mycount >= 1) {
echo "disabled";
}
}
```

but i figured that this works only once and if i were to change the date, the items within the div will not change =/

Comment: I don't know if MySQLi fixes that automatically, nor do I wish to run the risk. However, in case it doesn't, which I strongly assume, `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM burger WHERE timeslot = '$aa' ...");` is **vulnerable**! But maybe you are already taking care of that before the function call... I wouldn't know.

Comment: im actually still new to mysqli, infact this is my first time switching over.. i used to use mysql_real_escape_string, how do i make it invulnerable?

Comment: AFAIK, the MySQLi interface provides all functions that the MySQL interface provides as well. Thus you can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to counter hacking attempts just as you are used to with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Also, on a more topic related address, you should look into AJAX if you do not know it already. I think the other responses assume you already know of that technique, but I'm not so sure about that... [Tutorial @ W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a script that works every time the div element is clicked. So add an onClick event to div and then retrieve the required data from database on that event's handler.

Answer (score 0):

if your table does not have large amount of data, create a php file that behave as if it's a javascript file like that:

```
    <?php 
$js = 'data = new Array()';
$sql = 'select ...';
$count = 0;
while($row = fetch_rows($sql)){
  // do your check here
  $js .= 'data[' . $row['date'] . '] = new Array()';
  $js .= 'data[][' . $row['date'] . '][$count] . ' = "'.$row['item'] . '";';
  $count++;
}
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo $js;

?>
```

now you have a javascript array which have every date items, then on each click ask this array for that date key should return you the your options list

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `onchange` event of the ckeck box. Each time there is a change in the drop down, call the function to retrieve the values from the database.